# Using Powershell to get third table from a website

Tags: windows, powershell, web-scraping, html-parsing, powershell-4.0

I am trying to scrape the **Team Statistics** table from https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2020.html , but am not getting the full expected output.

My code:

```
#get the data
$data = Invoke-WebRequest $url

#get the first table
$table = $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("table") | Select -skip 2 | Select -First 1 |

#get the rows
$rows = $table.rows

#get table headers
$headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText

#count number of rows
$NumOfRows = $rows | Measure-Object

#Manually injecting TeamName
$headers = @($headers[0];'TeamName';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)])

#enumerate the remaining rows (skipping the header row) and create a custom object
$out = for ($i=2;$i -lt $NumofRows.Count;$i++) {
 #define an empty hashtable
 $objHash=[ordered]@{}
 #get the child rows
 $rowdata = $rows.item($i).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText 
 for ($j=0;$j -lt $headers.count;$j++) {
    #add each row of data to the hash table using the corresponding
    #table header value
    $objHash.Add($headers[$j],$rowdata[$j])
  } #for

  #turn the hashtable into a custom object
  [pscustomobject]$objHash
} #for
```

The output:

```
Special Teams Shot Data          
------------- ---------          
Rk            AvAge              
1             Washington Capitals
2             St. Louis Blues    
3             Boston Bruins      
4             Pittsburgh Penguins
5             Tampa Bay Lightning
6             New York Islanders 
7             Colorado Avalanche 
8             Columbus Blue Ja...
9             Carolina Hurricanes
10            Vancouver Canucks  
11            Philadelphia Flyers
12            Dallas Stars       
13            Edmonton Oilers    
14            Toronto Maple Leafs
15            Florida Panthers   
16            Vegas Golden Kni...
17            Arizona Coyotes    
18            Calgary Flames     
19            Winnipeg Jets      
20            Chicago Blackhawks 
21            Buffalo Sabres     
22            Montreal Canadiens 
23            Nashville Predators
24            New York Rangers   
25            Minnesota Wild     
26            San Jose Sharks    
27            Anaheim Ducks      
28            Ottawa Senators    
29            New Jersey Devils  
30            Los Angeles Kings  
31            Detroit Red Wings  
League Ave... 27.8
```

I believe my issue lies in what I am selecting, though I haven't been able to figure out how to select all the necessary parts for that specific table.

Ideally I'd like to get it looking near identical to what's on the website, but getting all the stats outputted is just as good.

Comment: `$rows.item(0).children` gives you the two merged headers at the very top. Grab `$rows.item(1)` instead and start the following loop with `$i = 2`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen so I changed it to: ```#get table headers
$headers = $rows.item(1).children | select -ExpandProperty InnerText ``` 
as well as changed
 ```#enumerate the remaining rows (skipping the header row) and create a custom object
for ($i=2;$i -lt $NumofRows.Count;$i++) {
```
But now I am faced with an issue where the team name is displayed in the AvAge row, when all the rest of the values should be shifted one row up.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  For example:
```Rk     : 1
AvAge  : Washington Capitals
GP     : 28.8
W      : 49
L      : 33
OL     : 11
PTS    : 5
PTS%   : 71
GF     : .724
GA     : 174
SOW    : 142
SOL    : 3
SRS    : 2
SOS    : 0.71
TG/G   : 0.04
EVGF   : 6.45
EVGA   : 138
PP     : 108
PPO    : 32
PP%    : 158
PPA    : 20.25
PPOA   : 27
PK%    : 171
SH     : 84.21
SHA    : 4
PIM/G  : 7
oPIM/G : 10.2
S      : 9.8
S%     : 1567
SA     : 11.1
SV%    : 1461
SO     : .903```
AvgAge should be 28.8, GP should be 49, etc etc

Comment: Looks like you'll manually need to inject the "TeamName" header: `$headers = @($headers[0];'TeamName';$headers[1..($headers.Length-1)])` before the `for` loop

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that worked! is it possible with my current code to have it formatted the same as the website? My output is currently displaying the headers for every team

Comment: @jackrabbit Just add `$out =` in front of your `For $i` so the result get assigned into `$out` instead of being displayed in the console, then you can use `$out | Out-GridView` or your preferred method (Could be a convertto-html) to display the results. PS won't display tables with more than 4 elements in the console.... As soon there's more than 4, it displays result as a list.

Comment: @SagePourpre thanks, and if I wanted to remove the 'Rk' column, and the last row entirely (League Average) , how would I go about doing so?

Comment: A select statement to only take what you want (you can change the column order if you wish too) `$out | Select P1,P2,P3` | Out-GridView`

Comment: @SagePourpre I got it to select the columns I wanted, but I still can't seem to find a way to not display the last row for League Averages